# How to use npm XLSX in meteor to read a .xlsx file on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, js-xlsx

I have to extract and read contents of an .xlsx file on browser using javascript framework meteor but I am unable to do it with npm XLSX modules.Can you please provide me a snippet to do it? Also I don't need to read text or csv file reading methods. Please do to a file with .xlsx extension only. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far and why is it not working? Do you get an error, incomplete data, etc?

Comment: Its all good but I get an error as _fs.fileSyncRead not found or ./dist/cpexcel.js is not found but this file is there. Its probably not loading.

Comment: Can you share your code where you are using this npm package?  Also, how did you add the npm package to your app?

Comment: I added package using cmd . meteor npm install xlsx. my code is as                     if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
    fs = require('fs');
    readFiles = $('#fu_excelFile')[0].files[0]; /// getting my file from input
     var workbook = XLSX.readFile(readFiles);

     var yourSheetsName = workbook.SheetNames;
      var a = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook[0]);
      // //   console.log(a);     Would these lines help you understand? Thank you Sir.